# On which format send file to save it on gridfs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hy every one,

Please , i 'm study on a project using nodeJS, and i would like to know , in which format my node client must send the file to the server ( is it in base64 format or else ?).

my client is :

```
//client.js

 $('#file').on('change', function(e){
    encode64(this);
 });

 function encode64(input) {
     if (input.files){                                
         chap.emit('test', { "test" : input.files[0] });                                
         var FR= new FileReader();
         FR.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
         FR.onload = function(e) {
            chap.emit('test', { "test" : e.target.result } );
         }                            
     }
}
```

My server side is :

```
 socket.on('test', function(e){
        var gs = new gridStore(db, e.test,"w");
        gs.writeFile(new Buffer(e.test,"base64"), function(err,calb){
            if (!err)
                console.log('bien passe');
            else
                console.log('erreur');
        });            
    });
```

But this doesn't work , i get this error :

```
TypeError: Bad argument
at Object.fs.fstat (fs.js:667:11)
```

Any one could help me ?

Comment: Binary/Raw. That is the point. Let the software ( which is what [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) is ) sort it out.

Comment: which is the module you are using to upload files?

Comment: I don't use any other module, just (gridFS) to upload files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is how you store into gridFs . I have used it to  store files. hope it works.

```
    fs = require('fs'),
    var gfs = require('gridfs-stream');
   var form = new multiparty.Form();

   form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
       var file = files.file[0]; 
        var filename = file.originalFilename; //filename
      var contentType = file.headers['content-type'];
    console.log(files)
    var tmpPath = file.path ;// temporary path
   var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({filename: fileName});
      // open a stream to the temporary file created by Express...
      fs.createReadStream(tmpPath)
            // and pipe it to gfs
            .pipe(writestream);
       writestream.on('close', function (file) {
        // do something with `file`

        res.send(value); 
    });
 })
```

Comment: Thanks , finally , i understand now , i must parse the file using multiparty

Comment: If you think my answer  helped you please upvote it and put tic mark. That's all you have to do. There is no resolved tag.

Comment: @MariyaJames please share the link for the complete example...thanks